# How does Google Swiffy implement clickTag for HTML5 banner ads?

Tags: html, flash-cs6, google-swiffy, clicktag, unminify

First, I tried finding an option to prevent Swiffy from compressing/minifying all the data when doing an export to HTML5 from Adobe Flash Pro. But no dice.

Even if I was able to read the unminified Javascript that Swiffy exported, I don't think there would be a simple function call for the "clickTag".
It's likely defining the variable clickTag in the huge haystack of `{index: #, type: #}`, and then doing processing each operations to eventually call the **window.open()** method (or something similar).

This is how it currently outputs (minified)
[image]

Does anyone have any clue how Swiffy implements clickTag? 
Or what would be the Javascript equivalent that does the same job?

Answer (score 1):

Swiffy uses the core API of the environment where the ad is served. If it's a DoubleClick Rich Media ad, it does use Enabler.exit("url").

If you want to have a better control on your output file, I'd suggest having a look at Google Web Designer. The closest experience to flash development in the HTML5 - JS era.

Answer (score 1):

Google instructions are [here](https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/3145300?hl=en), for plain HTML5 (non-swiffy) click tags.

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of the file is a snippet of code like this:

```
 <script>

  var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
      swiffyobject, {});

  stage.start();
```

Add this right before stage.start(); to mimic previous flash behavior. Ensure you use the proper capitalization.

```
  stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=http://stackoverflow.com");
```

**Note: Ensure to use url encoding if there are parameters...doesn't seem to like it otherwise

Comment: The problem with that snippet though is that it depends on referencing the runtime.js, and that's several kilobytes I'd rather not include in the ad just to support a clickTag functionality. Sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question that I'm hand-coding the HTML5 ads from scratch (not from Flash Pro).

Comment: If you are hand coding it then why not bind a click event to the body of the page?

Comment: That's essentially what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure what the "click" event has to call. Swiffy is supposedly compatible with *DoubleClick by Google*, but there's no sign of their EnablerJS script in the output of Swiffy (at least, not in the way DC's website explains one should implement it in HTML5). So that makes it more difficult to know what module/method to call, and which parameters to pass.